# Gravity Forms. I can’t go to field settings

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

A issue about WordPress Plugin : Gravity Forms.

For a few days now, a client can no longer go to the field settings. The tab just doesn’t seem to be clickable anymore. It is also impossible for him to add a field in the form. When we try to drag and drop a field, we get this visual bug (image) and nothing.

[screenshot backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxiRy.png)

Do you have an explanation? Has this ever happened to you?

Have a nice day,

Comment: have you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the PHP DOM extension isn't enabled on the server hosting the site. Ask the web host to enable that extension and then clear the browser cache before trying to edit the form again.

Comment: Hey richardW8k,

Thanks for this answer. I will try this  and I will keep you informed.
Have a nice day,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no errors displaying in the web console when you're performing this action. This can help pinpoint the exact location of the problem.